# pyinstaller проблема запуска .exe файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Написал такую программу:

```
print("Hello")
a = input()
```

Попытался скомпилировать ее в .exe при помощи PyInstaller. Прописал `pyinstaller test.py`
Он мне выдал:

```
142 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
143 INFO: Python: 3.7.6
143 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
146 INFO: wrote C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\test.spec
148 INFO: UPX is not available.
159 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\freQuensy\\PycharmProjects\\WinRepo',
 'C:\\Users\\freQuensy\\PycharmProjects\\WinRepo']
160 INFO: checking Analysis
170 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
171 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
177 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
191 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6072 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
6257 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6260 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\frequensy\pycharmprojects\winrepo\venv\scripts\python.exe
6285 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\test.py
6289 INFO: Processing module hooks...
6292 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
6453 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
6455 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
6867 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
6867 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
6879 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
7817 INFO: Looking for eggs
7818 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\freQuensy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.dll
7818 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
7838 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\build\test\warn-test.txt
7907 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\build\test\xref-test.html
7924 INFO: checking PYZ
7925 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
7925 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
8709 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
8732 INFO: checking PKG
8732 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
8733 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
8773 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
8776 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\frequensy\pycharmprojects\winrepo\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
8776 INFO: checking EXE
8778 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
8778 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
8779 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\build\test\test.exe
8796 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
8805 INFO: checking COLLECT
8807 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
8808 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
9419 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

После чего появилась папка build/test/test.exe
При запуске (2-ой клик) на сек появляется командная строка и пропадает. При запуске через cmd:

```
C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\build\test>test.exe
Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\freQuensy\PycharmProjects\WinRepo\build\test\python37.dll'.
LoadLibrary: ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
```

(Это не проблема с кодировкой, он действительно это выдал.)

Можете подсказать как решить эту проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте дописать флаг -F:
`pyinstaller -F test.py` Может поможет.
Иногда встречался с проблемой, что pyinstaller не хотел корректно компилить - решением стало установка более младшей версии питона.

Comment: Denis, спасибо, заработало, использовал флаг -F.